# PHP oci select returns rounded float on Windows Apache

Tags: php, decimal, oracle-call-interface

I have a weird issue when querying Oracle database. I get different results on exactly the same logic but on two different Windows Apache setups, which are actually the same version and configuration as far as I know.

The issue is that when I select 3 columns (   Number(10),Number(10),Number(10,4)   ) from a table the same query returns proper decimals on one machine for column #3 while on a different machine it removes the decimals and I get only the whole part of the number.

I have no idea what settings control how Oracle returns Number(10,4) data type, I don't see any differences in Oracle client, Apache, and PHP setups on the two machines.

What may be the cause of this?

Thanks ahead,

Ilya

Comment: This doesn't depend on Apache at all and in this case ... it's probably not related to PHP either. See if you have the same versions of the OCI driver.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out, I noticed that on the machine that looked like php oci oracle query "omits" decimals it was actually delimiting decimals with a comma, not a period. It had to do with NLS settings for displaying a number.

There are 3 levels of NLS settings: *DATABASE*, *INSTANCE* and *SESSION*. *SESSION* had the highest priority. So in order for a number to display in conventional format as 1,234.56 where thousands are separated by a comma and decimals by a period we need to set *NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS* to '.,' using the following command:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '.,'
```

I execute the command before any queries so all my numbers are now proper.

Comment: The OCI driver returns all numbers as PHP strings. I guess you weren't checking the actual values but the result after some PHP post-processing. Never mind, glad you fixed it and reported back.

Comment: Yes, I noticed it only when I actually got all the rows to display separately and clearly saw the values returned